# I use .so library and get NoSuchMethodError error

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, .so

I use .so library, as this

```
package ru.integrics.mobileschool.view.activity;

import android.util.Base64;

public class MainActivity {

    public MainActivity(){
        System.loadLibrary("x2");
    }
    public native String x01(String str);
    public String get(String str){
        String key = Base64.encodeToString(x01(str.substring(0, str.length() / 2)).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return key;
    }

}
```

But i get error:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: 
JNI CallObjectMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
no non-static method "Lru/integrics/mobileschool/view/activity/MainActivity;.getPackageManager()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;"
```

I tried set methods static, but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error you see it is complaining about a missing *Java method* because your `MainActivity` class does not inherit from the  `android.app.Activity` class, which provides the required `getPackageManager` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing `System.loadLibrary("x2");` wrongly. You should place it in a static block instead:

```java
package ru.integrics.mobileschool.view.activity;

import android.util.Base64;

public class MainActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("x2");
    }

    public MainActivity(){
        ...
    }
    public native String x01(String str);
    public String get(String str){
        String key = Base64.encodeToString(x01(str.substring(0, str.length() / 2)).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return key;
    }

}
```

And after that you have to confirm you have properly added `libx2.so` and there is a `x01(String)` function inside.